# How do I bump my project version on Gradle with a command similar to "npm version 1.5.0"?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to develop an automation to bump projects versions using Jenkins. For node projects I've already implemented this automation with `npm version {version}`, but for gradle projects not yet. I just got the version on build.gradle with:

```groovy
dir('examples/gradle'){
   def version = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "cat build.gradle | grep -o 'project.version = [^,]*'").trim()
   gradleProjectVersion = version.split(/=/)[1].trim()
}
```

Now I need to know a command similar to `npm version {version}` but for gradle so I can bump the project version with a value that I get in the name of my branch (and I already have the values that comes in the release branch).

I tried several commands I found here, my last attempt was:

```js
 dir('examples/gradle'){
  docker.image('gradle:6.8-jdk11').inside('-v /gradle:/home/gradle/.gradle/caches'){
    sh(script: "gradle -PprojVersion=${newProjectVersion}")
  }
  sh("git add .")
  sh("git commit -m \"chore(build.gradle): bump version to ${newProjectVersion}\"")
}
```

but it isn't changing the project version.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem using "writeFile". Now my pipeline can override my project version from gradle. Here's the code that I used:

```js
writeFile file: 'build.gradle', text: readFile('build.gradle').replaceAll(/project.version.*/, "project.version = \"${newProjectVersion}\"")
```